# Google Tag Manager - Capture domain on first page load in variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a situation where there is the same GTM container on six different domains. The user can potentially land on any of the six initially, but there are multiple user paths that can take them to one or more f the sites before making a purchase.

I need to know which website the user landed on *first*

I thought I could simply use a custom dimension set to page host, scoped to session. But in testing it looks like the *last* value is passed with the ecommm purchase tag vs the initial value set in the session.

So I am trying to use a custom javascript variable. I want to have it set an 'originSite' variable to the {{page hostname}} IF that variable was not previously set.

```
function () { 
var originSite;  
if (originSite == '' || originSite == null ) { 
  originSite = "{{Page Hostname}}"
  return originSite
} else { 
return originSite
}
}
```

But when I click over to another domain, this returns the new page hostname vs keeping it the same. So does declaring the var itself set this back to empty each time?

I also tried a DataLayer push that only fired once per session. But even with cross-domain set up for all the different sites, this is firing the first pageview of each domain. :(

Any assistance or suggestions would be appreciated...I'm struggling to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Re-declaring the variable is not the problem here, rather just a poor design. The problem is that JS context is wiped on page loads.

You want to preserve your variables explicitly if you want them to carry over through pageviews. The most common way to do so is via storing the values in cookies. People also use local storage, session storage, backend or even web sql for preservation.